# Unconfirmed transaction for 7days now, please i need help

Tags: mining-pools, blockchain.info, development, unconfirmed-transactions

Transaction to the  address 39j2nuZWr4F2hZ5wYDwQwZWzsTJC4H6ujn from my bitcoin wallet and it unconfirmed, i am new to this, i need help please, help me out